# Least squares interpolation in Octave

Tags: math, octave, interpolation, least-squares

I did a physics experiment, and got the following data:

```
R=[2.91 2.19 1.76 1.43 1.20 1.01 0.88 0.77 0.67 0.6 0.52 0.46 0.41 0.37];
t=[35:5:100];
T=t+273.15;
```

Now I need to do a least squares interpolation for the formula ln R = f(1 / T). I tried several methods from the web, but could  get none of them to work.

Comment: can you post what you tried and why they didn't give you the desired result?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7y8Y1kQT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are using linear lease square interpolation. The problem exists at the code for calculating coefficients.

This operation

```
A \ y
```

works when the column size of `A` matches with the row size of `y`.

But in your code, horizontal concatenation of `ones(n,1)` with `x` in the statement

```
A = [x ones(n,1)]
```

is not being allowed because the size of `x` is 1*14 and that of `ones(n,1)` is 14*1. Clearly, you are getting a dimensions mismatch error.

Here is a working code:

```
R=[2.91 2.19 1.76 1.43 1.20 1.01 0.88 0.77 0.67 0.6 0.52 0.46 0.41 0.37];
t=[35:5:100];
T=t+273.15;


function coeff = least_square (x,y)
    n = length(x);
    A = [ones(n,1) x];
    coeff = A \ y;
    plot(x,y,'x');
    hold on
    interv = [min(x) max(x)];
    plot(interv,coeff(1)*interv+coeff(2));
end


least_square(R', T');
```